# Can we have cloudera CDH5 configurations generator?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am using 5 node cloudera cluster ( 4 datanodes and 1 namenode ) to run CDH5 certification suite.

Each of the five nodes have 128GB of RAM and 40 CPU cores.
cert. suite fails with OutOfMemory errors.

( I am struggling to fix this for last 7-8 days without success. It also failed with default CDH configuration settings )
I have tried running the test suite by changing hell lot of combination of HDFS and YARN configurations. ( including JAVA_OPTS / MAVEN_OPTS ) etc.

I was thinking It would have been very useful / easy for users if there was an setting/app or something which could generate all ideal configuration files for given cluster setup. ( Considering RAM/CPU etc. )
i.e It will take info. from user like how many nodes, each nodes RAM, each nodes CPU etc and generate yarn, hdfs configuration parameters.

Answer (score 0):

We were facing the same issue, it turned out that the NFS was slow. Switching from NFS to local file system reduced the OOM errors.